# using css to color the background of specific areas of tds

Tags: css

Hi I'm trying to colour the tds of my table, but I want to specifically colour the background text within the td instead of the whole block. Is this possible ? I currently can target the images correctly but the text is a bit tricky.. http://jsfiddle.net/8gr2q5vm/3/

```
<td style="background-color: grey;"><img class="picture" src="#"></img></td>
<td class="birthday">Birthday: 1/1/1921 </td>
<td class="name">Name: barry</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your text in a `span` and then style your span element.

```
<td style="background-color: grey;"><img class="picture" src="#"></img></td>
<td class="birthday"><span style="background-color: grey;">Birthday: 1/1/1921</span></td>
<td class="name"><span style="background-color: grey;">Name: barry</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It would be better if you would have an external CSS file. And then you could import it and do some general styling like this:

```
td img, td span {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using an external css file it's just my appauling attempt of using js fiddle to display what i meant :) Thank you for the responses though very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text {
  background: #ff3300;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td style="background-color: grey;">
    <img class="picture" src="#"></img>
  </td>
  <td class="birthday"><span class=text>Birthday: 1/1/1921</span> 
  </td>
  <td class="name"><span class=text>Name: barry</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```